# Indexing after sub-grouping or sub-nesting in R

Tags: r, indexing, dataset, subset

Here is my dataset:

```
  record_id voucher_number ice
1          1           app1 app
2          1          00000   1
3          1          11111   1
4          1          22222   1
5          1          11111   2
6          2           app2 app
7          2          33333   1
8          2          44444   1
9          2          33333   2
10         2          33333   3
11         3           app3 app
12         3          55555   1
13         3          66666   1
14         3          55555   2
15         3          66666   2
16         3          55555   3
17         3          77777   1
```

Now after grouping by `record_id`, I want to create a new variable called `sets`. `sets` is supposed to be indexing column `voucher_number` in a way that when `ice` is `app`, `sets` variable is also `app` and when `voucher_number`  is a unique number/id with in a group, it is is indexed as 1, 2, 3, 4, and so forth.

I have used the following:

```
sets = match(voucher_number, unique(voucher_number))
```

This works okay but I am not able to exclude value `app` when indexing. What's the most efficient way to approach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`:

```
data <- read.table(text = "  record_id voucher_number ice
1          1           app1 app
2          1          00000   1
3          1          11111   1
4          1          22222   1
5          1          11111   2
6          2           app2 app
7          2          33333   1
8          2          44444   1
9          2          33333   2
10         2          33333   3
11         3           app3 app
12         3          55555   1
13         3          66666   1
14         3          55555   2
15         3          66666   2
16         3          55555   3
17         3          77777   1", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(record_id) %>% 
  mutate(sets = if_else(ice == "app",
                        "app",
                        as.character(row_number() - 1)))
# A tibble: 17 x 4
# Groups:   record_id [3]
   record_id voucher_number ice   sets 
       <int> <chr>          <chr> <chr>
 1         1 app1           app   app  
 2         1 00000          1     1    
 3         1 11111          1     2    
 4         1 22222          1     3    
 5         1 11111          2     4    
 6         2 app2           app   app  
 7         2 33333          1     1    
 8         2 44444          1     2    
 9         2 33333          2     3    
10         2 33333          3     4    
11         3 app3           app   app  
12         3 55555          1     1    
13         3 66666          1     2    
14         3 55555          2     3    
15         3 66666          2     4    
16         3 55555          3     5    
17         3 77777          1     6
```

## Edit

Unique values within the `voucher_number`s. Somehow I couldn't come up with an easy and clean solution just in basic `dplyr`, so I use `cur_group_id` to assign a unique ID and then use a custom function to let all IDs within every `record_id` group start with 1 and add the "app":

```
clean_id <- function(index, exclusion) {
  index_app <- which(exclusion %in% "app")
  correction_value <- min(index[-index_app])
  index <- as.character(index - correction_value + 1)
  index[index_app] <- "app"
  index
}

data %>% 
  group_by(record_id, voucher_number) %>%
  mutate(sets = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  group_by(record_id) %>% 
  mutate(sets = clean_id(sets, ice))

# A tibble: 17 x 4
# Groups:   record_id [3]
   record_id voucher_number ice   sets 
       <int> <chr>          <chr> <chr>
 1         1 app1           app   app  
 2         1 00000          1     1    
 3         1 11111          1     2    
 4         1 22222          1     3    
 5         1 11111          2     2    
 6         2 app2           app   app  
 7         2 33333          1     1    
 8         2 44444          1     2    
 9         2 33333          2     1    
10         2 33333          3     1    
11         3 app3           app   app  
12         3 55555          1     1    
13         3 66666          1     2    
14         3 55555          2     1    
15         3 66666          2     2    
16         3 55555          3     1    
17         3 77777          1     3
```

Comment: Thanks @starja! Lets add a layer to it. Please look at positions ```#3, #5, #7, #9 and #10``` where the voucher numbers are the same for 2 different ```record_id```, I want the ```set``` variable to say the same index if ```voucher_numbers``` are the same. What's the efficient way to approach that?

Comment: See my edit, does this work for you? Unfortunately, my code got a bit complicated now, maybe there are easier solutions

Comment: What does this ```cur_group_id()``` mean?

Comment: It's the [current id of the group](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html) to which a row belongs to; the grouping is generated by `group_by`

Comment: and also what this line ``` index <- as.character(index - correction_value + 1)``` here is doing?

Comment: `cur_group_id` gives a unique id over all combinations of `record_id` and `voucher_number`, so I correct within `record_id` group that the ids start with 1

Comment: In ```correction_value <- min(index[-index_app])``` , is ```min``` minus or minimum?

Comment: Okay I think I understand what's going on here, however, the ```dplyr``` loop is not understanding ```cur_group_id```

Comment: So here this ```dplyr::group_by(
      record_id,
      voucher_number
    ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      id = cur_group_id())
   ```                                                                                                                  This is not working and I am getting the error: ```Error in cur_group_id() : could not find function "cur_group_id"```

Comment: Also do you think if the ```record_id``` is integer, the function ```dplyr::mutate( y = cur_group_id``` will not be recognized?

Comment: `cur_group_id` is also from `dplyr` (I use 1.0.0)